# How to name Dataframes inside a List

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have created a basic list, and inside this list called *lista* (not big fantasy I know) there are 10 small dataframes.
Each one of this dataframes is called *"numberone","numbertwo",...,"numberten"*.

When I accede this list I can't see their names.
but the output I can see in the workspace (Rstudio) is this

[image]

This below is the code and my tries:

```
#creating multiple dataframes and a list and then give a title to this dataframes inside the list.

lista = list()
names = c("numberone","numbertwo","numberthree","numberfour","numberfive","numbersix","numberseven","numbereight","numbernine","numberten")

for (i in 1:10) {
  x = rnorm(10)
  df = data.frame(x)
  assign(names[i],df)
  lista[[i]] = df
}


#trying to change manually the names of the dataframes inside the "lista"  list

names(lista[1]) = "number one"
print(names(lista[1]))  #this gives no results

#trying using dput
output = dput(lista[1])

##trying put manually the name in front of the dput output to rename the first dataframe inside lista..
list('numberone'= structure(list(x = c(0.750704535096297, 1.16925878942967, 
                          0.806475114411396, 1.00973486249489, -0.301553383694518, 0.546485320708262, 
                          1.03645444095639, 0.247820396853631, -1.64294545886444, -0.216784798035195
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)))

#this seems to have renamed the first dataframe but, it's not working anyway
lista$numberone

print(names(lista[1])) #still no results
```

I've tried almost everything I could, but I can't give this single dataframes their names inside the list.

**How can i name these dataframes?**
Thank You

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to do `names(list)`

Here an example using empty lists

```r
list_test = vector("list",4)
names(list_test) = c("A","B","C","D")
list_test

$A
NULL

$B
NULL

$C
NULL

$D
NULL
```

With your example, I did:

```r
names(lista) <- names
```

and I get:

```r
names(lista)
[1] "numberone"   "numbertwo"   "numberthree" "numberfour"  "numberfive"  "numbersix"   "numberseven"
[8] "numbereight" "numbernine"  "numberten"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking to use double brackets (e.g.[[1]]) to reference elements in your list. Using your example code, this will work:

```
names(lista[[1]]) = "number one"
print(names(lista[[1]]))  #first element is now called "number one"
```

You can also use a setNames() function within a Map() function to rename each column for your list of dataframes.

```
lista <-Map(setNames, lista , names)
lista # each column is now assigned a name from your vector called names
```

To keep your code clean as possible, it is best to avoid naming objects with the same names as functions. (Your example code uses a vector called "names" but also uses names() function.)