# Name each df inside a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a large list with 6937 elements. Each dataframe inside the list represents a station that collects daily hydrological data.

In my file folder, each txt file is named with a code that represents the location of the station, and I need to keep the file name when I import the data into R.

**My question is, how do I import all these txt files into R while conserving their names?**

Name them (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620113/how-to-name-dataframes-inside-a-list)) once they are imported is impossible (as I mentioned there are 6000+ elements in the list)

This is how I imported each txt file into R:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readtext)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(purrr)


# Import all data

txt_files_ls <- paste("C:/Users/obarresi/Desktop/doc osvaldo/ana_data_acquisition/data_flow-ANA/All", 
                      list.files(path = "C:/Users/obarresi/Desktop/doc osvaldo/ana_data_acquisition/data_flow-ANA/All",
                                 pattern = "*.txt"), sep = "/")

txt_files_df_list <- vector("list", length(txt_files_ls))

txt_files_df_list <- lapply(txt_files_ls, 
                            function(x){data.frame(read.table(file = x, header = F,
                                                              sep ="", colnames(x)))})

#After all the cleaning process 
head(list[[1]])
#> day month year flow       date
37252  28    12 2001   35 2001-12-28
37253  29    12 2001   34 2001-12-29
37254  30    12 2001   37 2001-12-30
37255  31    12 2001   34 2001-12-31
37256   1     1 2002   34 2002-01-01
37257   2     1 2002   36 2002-01-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came up with a simple answer :

```r
files <- list.files(path="C:/Users/obarresi/Desktop/doc osvaldo/ana_data_acquisition/data_flow-ANA/All", pattern=".txt")

names(txt_files_df_list) <- files
```